# jQuery Ajax call gives error on iPhone

Tags: jquery, iphone, ajax

I have this $.ajax function, which runs fine on FF and other PC-browsers.
But when I try to access it using my iPhone, it fires the error event instead of the success event.

The page is jQuery mobile based, so it should work.

In the error, textStatus = 'error', but errorThrown isn't set, so I can't figure out where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your ajax call like this

```
formData = {
    // all your parameters here
    param1: param1,
    param2: param2
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "https://www.example.com/test",
    dataType: "json",
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
        //success handling
    },
    error: function(data) {
        //error handling
    }
});
```

And your URL can request and response JSON data. Please refer this site for more information.

http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/02/25/crud-operation-using-jquery-mobile-on-android-part-2/

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/